# Font size on different devices

Tags: android, textview, font-size

I use `sp` for my `TextView` font size
But the size in mobiles and tablets is similar

My xml :

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Register"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Output :

[image]

What I want :

[image]

Comment: try this library https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-on-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save different layout for different sizes in drawable files.
In each folder you have separate xml file.
In each xml you can define different`android:textSize`.

For example, in:

- drawable-hdpi folder:
  `android:textSize = "10sp"`
- drawable-ldpi folder:
  `android:textSize = "12sp"`
- drawable-mdpi folder:
  `android:textSize = "14sp"`
- drawable-xhdpi folder:
  `android:textSize = "16sp"`
- drawable-xxhdpi folder:
  `android:textSize = "18sp"`

Answer (score 1):

you can use different qualifiers for each xml or values file.

ie, if you want same design with different styles,you can use 2 styles.xml files with different qualifiers.for eg styles.xml and styles-sw600dp.xml
this creates a general style and a 7" tablet style.
here sw600dp denotes smallest width as 600dp which is typically used in 7" tabs.

You can get a detailed overview of [Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) in the Android documentation.

you can also define different layouts with the help of qualifiers